# Is it required to credit author of software released under the MIT license?

Tags: licensing, legal

I make some changes in console application that was released under the MIT license but i don't understand much about the license. Is it required to credit the original author in it and do i need to credit myself for changes?

Comment: have you read the text of the license?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MIT license](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT) specifically requires you to retain the copyright holder's copyright notice.

That means YES, you must credit the original author.

Comment: ok, but do i need to credit to myself if i made some changes?